# Should I validate/sanitize $_SESSION variables in php?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm building a quiz site, where I store some variables 
(time taken to answer, which answer-option was chosen by the user etc etc) in `$_SESSION`s after each question - where I put those stats into the DB only after the user finishes the quiz.

I've implemented a few `if`'s to check if those `$_SESSION` variables are numbers (`is_numeric()`). Also I validate the length (`strlen()`) etc.

- But is there a reason to do that?
- Or is it enough just to `real_escape_string()` those before storing them
  in MySQL?
- Also if there would be many users, then won't that put a big load on
  the server?

Comment: If you're interested in preventing SQL injection, you should use PDO or mysqli with parametrized statements. That way, no matter what you insert, it will never be evaluated as MySQL code.

Comment: The case is that I'm not talking only about SQL injections. Isn't there any other way someone can attack my site using variables passed by user?

Comment: @joe007 yes, like XSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, since you set them yourself.

Unless of course you deduce them directly from user input in which case the exact same rules that apply to every bit of user input apply.

There is nothing special about `$_SESSION` variables. You need to sanitize user input when you receive it from the user - regardless if you store it in a database, a session, or so on.

Like JPod suggested - when performing SQL queries - always use prepared queries which mitigate SQL injection.

Comment: Yes, but let's say I set the $_SESSION variable on _page1_ then it is read on _page2_. If I sanitize it on _page1_ and doesn't care about it on _page2_, then a hacker/cracker can just simply send malicious code/stuff via $_SESSION directly to _page2_ using some software?

Comment: @joe007 the front end user has no direct access to `$_SESSION`, _you're_ the one putting things there. If you sanitize the input _before_ you put it in the session variable (and you _should always do that_) it's not magically going to become unsafe. More generally, you should sanitize everything you get from the client religiously and with no mercy - it has to be clear, consistent, explicit and in one place. There should be no doubt what data is dirty and what data is clean.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't knew that the user can't rewrite $_SESSION somehow. Thank you very much :)